# How to signal PID in C

Tags: c

C is alittle new to me. I have two executables, one is  writeP and one is a readP. WriteP executable writes to shared array and read but readP awaits until write is completed it's task.

How it;s suppose to execute is as followed. WriteP Executable writes to 10 arrays and waits for a signal. ReadP, sits in busy awaits until write gives a signal. Once a signal is given it read through the 10 arrays and prints the value. I've got that working perfect. Now I would like to add one more iteration.

WriteP, writes to 10 arrays and waits. ReadP, reads 10 arrays and sends a signal to writeP to write to the next 10 arrays. ReadP is to sit and await for the signal.

May I ask how come my code won't iterate the next 10 arrays?

readP.c

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])  //expects pid of writer as clarg
{
    int i, *pint, *pint1, shmid;
    int pid = atoi(argv[1]);

    shmid = shmget(SHMKEY, 128, 0666);
    pint = (int*) shmat(shmid, 0, 0);

    /*busy wait until writer sets the flag to indicate writer finished writing*/
    while(*pint != -1);

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            printf("%d\n", *pint++); /* display sh. mem */

    kill(pid, 10); /* send signal to shwrite that's OK to remove shmem */
    printf("signal just sent \n");

    /*busy wait until writer sets the flag to indicate writer finished writing*/
    while(*pint != -1) ;


    for(i = 10; i < 20; i++)
            printf("%d\n", *pint++); /* display sh. mem */

    kill(pid, 10); /* send signal to shwrite that's OK to remove shmem */
}
```

writeP.c

```
int main (void)
{
    int *pint, *ppint, i;



    /* force any signal from 1-20 sent to this process to call handler
    cleanup, which will detach shared mem before exiting */
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            signal(i, cleanup);

    shmid = shmget(SHMKEY, 128, 0666|IPC_CREAT);
    pint = (int*) shmat(shmid, 0, 0);
    ppint = pint;

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            *ppint++ = i; /* load sh. mem with ints 0-10 */
    *pint = -1;  /* load -1 into start of shmem */


    printf("First break point");

    pause(); /* wait here until a signal occurs--eg, kill from reader */

    printf("Second break point");

    for(i = 10; i < 20; i++)
            *ppint++ = i; /* load sh. mem with ints 0-10 */
    *pint = -1;  /* load -1 into start of shmem */

    pause(); /* wait here until a signal occurs--eg, kill from reader */


    return 0;
}
```

Sample execution

```
./writeP &
> 24858   // memory address

./readP 24858
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon, but even more importantly,
please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]). You've not provided enough to to be an MCVE.  There are critical functions like the `cleanup` function that are missing.  You claim to set signal handlers for signals 1..20; you actually do so for 0..19.  Some of those will fail — not just 0, but also SIGKILL (usually 9), and maybe some others too.  This isn't critical, but it is sloppy thinking. `pint` and `ppint` point to the same place; that's confusing.  There isn't enough debug printing.

Comment: You say "ReadP, sits in busy awaits until write gives a signal."... but writeP never performs a "kill()" ... so it never sends a signal to readP

Comment: This logic can be easily implemented with a named mutex.